# SQL: Find diff between two tables with non-unique feature IDs?

Tags: sql

I have two tables both of which have the same two columns: feature ID and language.  I want to pull out records where the language has changed for the feature ID. The problem, though, is that there are multiple languages for each feature ID. My tables look like:

Table 1

```
Feature ID  | Language
------------------------
001         | 'en'
001         | 'es'
001         | 'pt'
002         | 'es'
002         | 'fr'
```

Table 2

```
Feature ID  | Language
-----------------------
001         | 'es'
001         | 'en
001         | 'fr'
002         | 'fr'
002         | 'es'
```

I initially tried something like:

```
SELECT a.feature_id, b.feature_id, a.language, b.language 
FROM table 1 a FULL OUTER JOIN table 2 b on a.feature_id = b.feature_id 
WHERE a.language <> b.language
```

but this didn't work exactly as I hoped. I'm noticing results like:

```
002 | 002 | 'fr' | 'es'
002 | 002 | 'es' | 'fr'
```

Is there a way in SQL to alleviate this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.feature_id, b.feature_id, a.language, b.language
FROM [table 1] a FULL OUTER JOIN [table 2] b on a.feature_id = b.feature_id 
    and a.language = b.language
WHERE a.feature_id is null or b.feature_id is null
```

Change it to a full outer join on language and feature and then a where clause to filter down to those rows without a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON featureID and Language. then if language language from TABLE2 will be NULL it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.feature_id, b.feature_id, a.language, b.language 
FROM table 1 a FULL OUTER JOIN table 2 b on a.feature_id = b.feature_id 
WHERE a.feature_id || a.language <> b.feature_id || b.language
```

Or:

```
SELECT a.feature_id, b.feature_id, a.language, b.language 
FROM table 1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN table 2 b 
on a.feature_id || a.language <> b.feature_id || b.language  
WHERE b.feature_id is NULL
```